# how to download a generated .csv file in a multi server environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a job that creates .csv files and saves them in a directory called exports in the rails root. I also have a controller that downloads the files like this:

```
def download_export
  @export = Export.find(params[:id])

  export_file = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/exports/#{@export.name.gsub(/\s/,'_')}_#{@export.id}.csv"

  if File.exists?(export_file)
    options = {:filename => "Export (#{@export.name.gsub(/\s/,'_')}_#{@export.id}).csv", :type => "text/csv"}
    options = options.merge({:x_send_file => true}) if Rails.env != "development"
    send_file export_file, options
  else
    flash[:notice] = "<h3>Export data is not available.</h3>"
    redirect_to :action => "index"
  end
end
```

Basically everything works as expected when running on a single server. The production environment has been scaled to two servers behind a balancer. There is a nightly task that checks to see if any exports are in the queue, and if so it generates the file. This task always runs on only one instance.

Is my best bet to create a symbolic link from the other server to the directory where the file is being saved? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What if part of the process that generates the csv export also rsyncs the directory with the other server? The redundancy might possibly be beneficial if the other server is down...

[How to Synchronize Directories with Rsync](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/09/how-to-synchronize-directories-with-rsync/)

Answer (score 0):

It's very common in multiple host environments to need to sync things. Why not look into using [`rsync`](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/), which is designed for that purpose, or [rcp](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?rcp) or [scp](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?scp) which aren't as smart but equally capable of moving files around?

You can do it two different ways: pushing from the source host to secondary hosts, or, have the secondary hosts go get the data.

Personally, I'd probably go with the first scenario. Set up a cron job that launches a shell script that checks to see if files are ready to be pushed. If so, rsync (or scp/rcp) them over, and, if the push is successful, delete them from the source directory.

On the secondary hosts have a cron job that fires off periodically, looking for files to import. If there are no files immediately exit. If there are some in the incoming directory, load them then delete them, then exit.

The rsync article linked to has several examples that could probably help you get started.